# (TypeError): dayDataFiltered[0] is undefined

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I'm trying to figure out a way to show my city current temperature in React's [Navbar](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/navbar/) through [React Open Weather](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-open-weather), using <Navbar.Text> and  as my components, it will show "Loading" in the navBar and then it wont compile giving the error

> Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): dayDataFiltered[0] is undefined

I followed all the steps from the Open Weather component except this one since I couldnt really understand it

> you will need to add link to weather icons css file in your html file or require it in your build process Weather Icons, or you can directly use the CDN.

```
<link
  rel="stylesheet"
  href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/weather-icons/2.0.9/css/weather-icons.min.css"
  type="text/css"
/>
```

And here's a shortened piece of the code

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import Modal from 'react-bootstrap/Modal'
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'
import {Navbar,Nav,NavDropdown} from 'react-bootstrap';
import {NavLink} from 'react-router-dom';
import './NavBar.css';
import ReactWeather from 'react-open-weather';


export default function NavBar (){

  const [show, setShow] = useState(false)

  const handleClose = () => setShow(false);
  const handleShow = () => setShow(true);

  

    return(
      
      <Navbar collapseOnSelect expand="lg" bg="dark" variant="dark">
         <Navbar.Brand as={NavLink} to= '/' className={"px-3"}>
           <h4 className={"fontSize4"}>Home</h4>
         </Navbar.Brand>
...
...
...
              <Nav>
              <Navbar.Text>
              <ReactWeather
                forecast="today"
                apikey="my actual key"
                type="city"
                city="Munich"
              />
              </Navbar.Text>
               <Nav.Link  as={NavLink} to= '/Login' className={"px-3"}>
                 <h4 className={"fontSize4"}>Login / Sign Up</h4>
               </Nav.Link>
              <Nav.Link as={NavLink} to= '/AboutUs' className={"px-3"} >
                 <h4 className={"fontSize4"}>About us</h4>
              </Nav.Link>
              </Nav>
           </Navbar.Collapse>
         </Navbar>


    );
  
}
```

And this is how it looks
[image]

Thanks for the help

Comment: Maybe this can help ? https://github.com/farahat80/react-open-weather/issues/30 . As a suggestion. Avoid using plugins that are no longer maintained

Comment: @MihaiT Didn't apply for my error but thank you, do you know any other ways to display temperature in a Navbar like this?

Comment: It has nothing to do with the navbar. Just find a suitable plugin that is maintained or more downloads. Also there are some docs on the web about this. Like this one https://medium.com/@leizl.samano/how-to-make-a-weather-app-using-react-403c88252deb . Read through it and extract what you need.

Comment: @MihaiT They use classes to fetch API calls, trying to do it in the function navbar does not work, I'm very new to web development, where should I look?